# Button onclick in expandablelistview

Tags: java, android, xml

**ExpandableListAdapter**
**Hi i need to get onclick event to the button in List_item.xml whein i click on the button.
im beginning with java and android development. im searching for solution for 3 days**

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List < String > _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap < String, List < String >> _listDataChild;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List < String > listDataHeader,
                             HashMap < String, List < String >> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
    Button btnListChild = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn);


    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);



    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);


    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

**list_item.xml - there is the button**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorACD_white"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:background="@color/colorACD_white"
        android:textColor="@color/colorACD_black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/sourcesansproregular"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/robotoregular"
        android:text="Edit">
    </Button>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="391dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="popup"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Dialog.xml - the window i want to open when i click on the button from list_item**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="122dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="133dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="297dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="121dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="312dp"
        android:background="@color/colorACD_orange" />

</RelativeLayout>

**My Dialog Java class**

    package com.example.application.example;
public class ExampleDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
    
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Information")
                .setMessage("This is a Dialog")
                .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added an interface to your adapter. Now from where you are creating this adapter you need to implement the interface `ExpandableListAdapterInterFace` and the `buttonClicked` method, you can change the arguments and their types as per your need.

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private final ExpandableListAdapterInterFace _expandableListAdapterInterFace;

    interface ExpandableListAdapterInterFace{
        void buttonClicked(String dataHeader,int position);
    }

    //........ your code............

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData, ExpandableListAdapterInterFace expandableListAdapterInterFace) {
        this._context = context;
        this._expandableListAdapterInterFace=expandableListAdapterInterFace;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    //..............your code .........


    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        Button btnListChild = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btnListChild.setOnClickListener(v->{
            _expandableListAdapterInterFace.buttonClicked(childText,childPosition);
        });

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }
   //..................your code............
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.